# Changing Html content from Javascript with data from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, variables, undefined

My code is behaving strangely. Indeed, I created my data in a JSON object:

```
injectJson = {
   "title": "Questions for a champion",
   "rules": [
      {
        "idChrono": "chrono-minute",
        "text": "Top is gone!",
        "tag": [
            {
                "id": "chronometer",
                "text": "countDown"
            }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="rules">
   <h3>The game's rules!</h3>
</div>
<div id="begin">
   <a href="#" class="link">Begin</a>
</div>
```

And here is the Javascript code with which I inject the HTML code:

```
selectLinkBegin = document.getElementById("begin");
selectLinkBegin.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", function(injectJson) {
    // Injection code
    selectRules = document.getElementById("rules");;
    selectRules.firstElementChild.innerText = injectJson.rules[0].texte;
});
```

In my computer,the JSON object and the JavaScript code are in the same .js file. I load my script at the end of the body tag.
When I open my .html code in the browser, the console displays:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.

But when I copy the Javascript code into the console, I get the expected result: h3's text content is updated.

**Demo:**

```js
injectJson = {
  "title": "Questions for a champion",
  "rules": [{
    "idChrono": "chrono-minute",
    "text": "Top is gone!",
    "tag": [{
        "id": "chronometer",
        "text": "countDown"
      }

    ]
  }]
}


selectLinkBegin = document.getElementById("begin");
selectLinkBegin.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", function(injectJson) {
  // Injection code
  selectRules = document.getElementById("rules");;
  selectRules.firstElementChild.innerText = injectJson.rules[0].texte;
});
```

```html
<div id="rules">
  <h3>The game's rules!</h3>
</div>
<div id="begin">
  <a href="#" class="link">Begin</a>
</div>
```

Can you explain to me what is going on? How to remedy this? I have already emptied my cache but it's still the same.

Comment: Need to remove the `injectJson` parameter from your click handler, and use `text` property instead of `texte`.

Comment: Try changing "function(injectJson)"  to "function(event)"

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry for thsi typo. I translate my code from French

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the variable `injectJSON`  is being hoisted by the param in your `click` event handler callback `function`, so it will be `undefined` that's why you got the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined at HTMLAnchorElement.

In other words the `callback` param has the same name as your `injectJson` variable, so that means your original `injectJson` variable will be `undefined`, as it was `overridden` by this param.

You can check [the **Variable Hoisting** section here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/) for further reading about this.

So what you need to do is to remove the callback param:

```
selectLinkBegin.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Injection code
  selectRules = document.getElementById("rules");;
  selectRules.firstElementChild.innerText = injectJson.rules[0].text;
});
```

**Note:**

- Make sure to access the right `text` element instead of `texte` in
  `injectJson.rules[0].texte`.
- Make sure to declare your variables with `var` keyword and avoid using an existing variable name, to avoid such problems.

**Demo:**

```js
var injectJson = {
  "title": "Questions for a champion",
  "rules": [{
    "idChrono": "chrono-minute",
    "text": "Top is gone!",
    "tag": [{
        "id": "chronometer",
        "text": "countDown"
      }

    ]
  }]
}


selectLinkBegin = document.getElementById("begin");
selectLinkBegin.firstElementChild.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Injection code
  selectRules = document.getElementById("rules");;
  selectRules.firstElementChild.innerText = injectJson.rules[0].text;
});
```

```html
<div id="rules">
  <h3>The game's rules!</h3>
</div>
<div id="begin">
  <a href="#" class="link">Begin</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Can you please explain me what is the callback?

Comment: @FEUJIOMarieTherese the `callback` is the `function` you pass to the `click` event handler in: `addEventListener("click",function() {...})`.